# mount windows disk after error mounting

Tags: mount, ntfs

I can't mount the windows disk. I am a new Linux user.

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/dimitris/CE061FB2061F9B13:
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/dimitris/CE061FB2061F9B13"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.

Failed to mount /dev/sda1: Operation not permitted:
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to write on the disc, or just make a backup?

The error message tells you - `unsafe state` - you can mount it read only `ro` option:

```
mount -t "ntfs" -o  "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177,ro" "/dev/sda1" "/media/dimitris/CE061FB2061F9B13"
```

you can try to remove the hibernate:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 "/media/dimitris/CE061FB2061F9B13"
```